# Magento 2 model for adding images to media folder (not for products)?

Tags: magento2, image, model, media-images

When not working with products, is there a magento2 model/function that can be used for reading/writing images to the media folder? (like `addImageToMediaGallery` / `getMediaGalleryProcessor()->addImage` used when working with products).

I've made a module that loads data from an api/json link into to a custom table where one column is an image URL.
I wan't to save the image from the link to the local media folder.

I know I can do this with PHP (file_put_contents, fwrite, curl), but I'm thinking there must be a "Magento way" to do this?

I get the image url by 
`$image = $this->myRepository->getImageUrl($data['image_url']);`

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

I just used `Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File;` and `$this->file->read($originalImageUrl, $newImage);`